# Make a loop were a random value changes every time the loop restarts

Tags: java, loops, random, while-loop

I am making a coin flip simulator, but I have a problem with the random values. I need to make a random value that changes every time the while-loop starts again.

```
    System.out.println("How many times do I flip the coin?");
    int repetition;
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;
        Scanner amount_of_times = new Scanner(System.in);
    repetition = amount_of_times.nextInt();
    double luck = (Math.random());
    do {
        if (luck > 0.5)
            heads++ ;
        else
            tails++ ;
        repetition --;
    } while (repetition > 0);
    System.out.println("The amount of heads was " + heads + ", meanwhile the amount of tails was " + tails + ".");
        amount_of_times.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `double luck = (Math.random());` inside your loop

Comment: Please see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to `luck` only once, **before** the loop. If you want it to get a different value in each iteration, you should move the assignment to it **inside** the loop:

```
do {
    double luck = Math.random(); // Here!
    if (luck > 0.5)
        heads++ ;
    else
        tails++ ;
    repetition --;
} while (repetition > 0);
```